# TestSuite JUnit -> Each TestCase has same @Before etc

Tags: junit, test-suite

I'm just writing som Selenium WebDriver tests with JUnit 4.

Test Cases are grouped by JUnit TestSuite. Each test case (test class) has the same @Rule @BeforeTest @AfterTest

How can i realize this in JUnit TestSuite, so that I don't have the same code for @Rule, @BeforeTest and @AfterTest in each test case (class)?

//edit:  maybe i define an abstract testcase class, which i extend from each test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge the code of @Rule, @BeforeTest and @AfterTest into a single rule.

```
public class TheMergedRule implements TestRule {
  private final TestRule theCurrentRule = ...

  public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description) {
    return new Statement() {
      theCodeOfBefore();
      theCurrentRule.apply(base, description);
      theCodeOfAfter();
    }
  }

  public void theCodeOfBefore() {
    ...
  }

  public void theCodeOfAfter() {
    ...
  }
}
```